# Install PyQt on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pyqt4

I downloaded the sip zip file, extracted, then and I ran

```
python configure.py
```

I can see the folders and files created in my C drive after running the configure file.

Next I read in the docs that I need to run below command to install the sip components

```
(MAKE) install
```

But I am getting this error : 'install was unexpected at this time.'

Please suggest if 'make install' should be run or I can proceed with installing PyQt.

Comment: I went with windows installer, it worked for me.